# multithreading problems in project

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I'm trying to implement multi-threading in my project, but I'm new to this concept. Hope someone can help me! Here are my two questions:

**1**.I'm trying to do the multi-thread on the function of insert-subreddits to insert to the database. However, when I read_sql, it shows that the **subreddits_df** is an **Empty DataFrame**. The insert_subreddits works fine without multi-threading, so I think it read_sql before inserting to the database. Is there any way to **wait** until the line of **executor.map all completed** **and then read the sql?**
**2**. Not sure is it ok to use both **executor.map and executor.submit** in 
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    executor.map(insert_subreddits,[i for i in range(len(chosen_subreddits))])
    subreddits_df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM main_subreddits", con) # <clddlass 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
    print(subreddits_df)
    args_list = gen_args_list(subreddits_df)
    future_results = {executor.submit(insert_to_db, *arg): arg for arg in args_list}
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_results):
        try:
            _ = future.result()
        except Exception as exc:
            print('generated an exception: %s' % exc)
```

function of insert_subreddits

```
def insert_subreddits(i):
    subreddit = reddit.subreddit(chosen_subreddits[i]) # get subreddit by a string name 
    #scrape all the posts and their comments from a list of subreddits
    # store subreddit data into the database
    db_tuple = (subreddit.id, chosen_subreddits[i], subreddit.title, int(subreddit.created), 0)
    print(db_tuple)
    sql_query = """INSERT INTO main_subreddits VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""
    cur.execute(sql_query, db_tuple) # use tuple to insert
```

Comment: Is `insert_to_db` thread safe?

Comment: Yes it is safe!

Comment: Please extract and provide a [mcve]. It is required here and helps you understand the issue yourself. In particular multithreading is a complex topic which you can't just throw into an application.

Comment: I have edited it